# Loop through file to count field number

Tags: awk

I have a script bash to add users from a .txt file.
It is really simple:

```
name firstname uid gid
```

space separated values

I want to check with awk if each row contains 4 fields. If yes I want to return 1, if not return 0.

```
file=/my/file.txt
awk=$(awk -F' ' '{(NF != 4) ? res = 0 : res = 1; print res)}' $file)
echo $awk
```

Right now, awk returns 1 for each row, but I want it to return 1 or 0 at the end, not for each line in the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On UNIX you'll return `0` in case of success and `!=0` in case of an error. For me it makes more sense to return `0` when all records have `4` fields and `1` when not all records have 4 fields.

To achieve that, use [`exit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html):

```
awk 'NF!=4{exit 1}' file
```

FYI: `awk` will exit with `0` by default.

If you want to use it in a shell conditional:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! awk 'NF!=4{exit 1}' file ; then
    echo "file is invalid"
fi
```

---

PS: `-F' '` in your example is superfluous because `' '` is the [default field delimiter](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html#Default-Field-Splitting).

Comment: A superior approach indeed !

Comment: *"Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away."*   Saint-Exupery

Comment: @karakfa Thank you! :) Fortunately awk's amazing design allows to write such things.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for adding that detail to the discussion! Sure, you are right. Please don't bear with me that I don't add it to my answer because it's kind of expert knowledge. But I will remind myself on that (hopefully! :) ).

Comment: Ah, nvm! I've changed my answer... Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Was duping this answer to one asked today [Check if the file has given number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130135/check-if-the-file-has-given-number-of-columns). OP ended up doing this for an empty file, for which it does not return invalid case. Do you think it should be handled?

Comment: @Inian Good point. Feel free to add it. I'm busy atm, but I can also look at this in the evening.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
awk 'res = NF!=4{exit} END{exit !res}' file
```

This will exit with `1` if all rows have 4 columns otherwise it will exist with `0`

Comment: You don't need the `END` block and the `res` variable. Just `NF!=4{exit 1}` does the trick. You would need the `res` variable mechanism only if there would be an `END` block already. That's because `exit` will still run the `END` block.

Comment: `NF!=4{exit 1}` does reverse, it returns `0`  for good case and `1` for bad case

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misread the question then. But if that is the case then probably the OP misunderstood the trueishness of `1` and `0` in shell scripts. For me it does not make sense to return `1` if all records have `4` fields.

Comment: Yes because OP wrote `if each row contains 4 fields. If yes I want to return 1, if not return 0`

Comment: Yes, saw that now. Let's see if the OP *really* wants that :)

Comment: @hek2mgl & anybhava the OP has thrown you both by using the ambiguous/meaningless word `return`. An awk script doesn't `return` anything - it prints something and it exits with a status. So when the OP says `return 1` does he want the script to print `1` or exit with status `1`? When printing, 1 often means success while 0 means failure but when exiting 0 means success and 1 failure. From the OPs code, he's not using the exit status but IMHO he should be and then what hek2mgl suggested would be correct - `awk 'NF!=4{exit 1}'`

Comment: @EdMorton For me the term `return value of a program` is valid because it is the value which the `main()` function returns. But I'm sure my vocabular needs adjustment! ;)

Comment: To me talking about a "return" in this context is like taking about searching text for a "pattern" - it's just confusing and easily avoided. Use "output" or "exit status" instead of "return" (and use "string" or "regexp" instead of "pattern") and then everyone knows exactly what you're talking about with no confusion or the inevitable associated bugs!

Answer (score 0):

Subtle changes to your script would do

```
result=$(awk -F' ' 'BEGIN{flag=1}NF!=4{flag=0;exit}END{print flag}' "$file")
[ ${result:-0} -eq 0 ] && echo "Problematic entries found in file"
```

**The approach**

- set the flag to 1 hoping that every record would contain 4 fields.
- check if record actually contains 4 fields, if not set flag to zero and exit.
- And `exit` would skip the rest of the input and go to the `END` rule.
- print the flag and store it in result.
- Check the result and proceed with the action course.