# Check if the file has given number of columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk, csv

I have a few csv files that I need processing if the number of columns is 4 througout the file

file_1 :

```
1,aa,bb,cc
2,dd,ee,ff
3,gg,hh,ii
```

file_2 :

```
1,xx
2,yy
3,zz
4,xy
```

I'm using awk for this

```
for file in file_1 file_2 ... file_n
do
    if [[ `awk -F"," 'NF==4' $file` ]]
    then
        #process
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

I'm looking for a solution that

- Doesn't involve a subshell
- Checks for number of columns throughout the file
- Performs better than the above code (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
for f in file_1 file_2 file_n; do
   if awk -F, 'NF!=4{exit 1}' "$f"; then
      echo "good $f"
   else
      echo "bad $f"
   fi
done
```

This `awk` exits with `1` as soon it finds a record with no of columns not equal to `4`.

Comment: I had to dupe it, found an _exact_ replica on second time search. ;)

Comment: @Inian my search skills are not as good as you I guess ;)

Comment: @anubhava your code is not working for blank files

Comment: @Nitesh: Empty file has no record of `num_columns != 4` hence it is considered a good case. If you want to change that then replace `awk` line with `[[ -s $f ]] && awk -F, 'NF!=4{exit 1}' "$f"`

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** If you want to check that any line is NOT having 4 fields and move to next file then following may help you on same.

```
awk -F, 'NF!=4{nextfile} 1' File_*
```

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to skip only those lines which are NOT having 4 fields then following may help you on same.

```
awk -F, 'NF!=4{next} 1' File_*
```

Comment: if i put these conditions in IF, these conditions return all rows that have 4 columns and ignore the other rows .. but they're helpful in other conditions